# How to unit test a circuit breaker?

Tags: c#, fallback, circuit-breaker

I am using an external service for metatagging my pages. I implemented circuit breaker as well as fallback for it and is working perfectly. Now I want to write unit tests for it. Any thoughts?

I am pasting some part of my code for your review:

Unity Registration

```
.RegisterType<ITaggerRepository>(new InjectionFactory(c => Framework.CrossCutter.ApplyAspectsTo((ITaggerRepository)c.Resolve<CachedTaggerRepository>(), "TaggerRepository").Configure<ISlaAspectConfiguration<ITaggerRepository>>(config => config.Fallback = new TaggerRepositoryFallback())
.Proxy));
```

Fallback implementation:

```
public class TaggerRepositoryFallback : ITaggerRepository
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Requests the tags.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="request">The request.</param>
    /// <returns>Tagger response</returns>
    public TaggerResponse RequestTags(TaggerRequest request)
    {
        return new TaggerResponse
        {
            Url = request.PageUrl,
```

Comment: Have you tried anything, and are having a specific problem? I think the answer to this might be opinion based, which is off-topic. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: dont even know where to start!!! :(